# Error Value: 2147942402 on PowerShell scheduler Task

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to create a Scheduled Task on a Windows Server Core 2012 so I don't have the UI of the scheduler task on the server, I've created the task with the following ps command:

```
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $jobname -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -RunLevel Highest -User $username -Password $password
```

I'm trying to execute a C# executable with the following action command:

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "D:\Apps\DeleteReadsDuplicates\DeleteReadsDuplicates.exe"
```

but it's not finding the file.

Do you think I have to execute the .exe with powershell and the file location as a parameter?

Comment: Does the user running the scheduled task have access to the executable's file path?

Comment: I think I had a typo on the executable path, now it's working, any way, thank you.